# How to refresh snapshot in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

How can I refresh the snapshot of a FutureBuilder? I have a tabcontroller with a dismissable FutureBuilder on one tab. I implemented the ondismissed events the following:

```
onDismissed: (direction) async {
setState(() async {
      await MyContent().delete(snapshot.data[index]);
      myContents = getMyContents(myContent.id);
});
},
```

I tested the flow, the delete works, the myContents list returns the correct number of elements, the element really disappears from the list, but when I navigate to another tab and back, the deleted element appears again. Just closing the page and reopening show the correct element.

The problem is the snapshot that is not refreshing:

```
FutureBuilder<List<MyContent>>(
future: myContents,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {
return new ListView.builder(
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: calling await in setState is the the worst thing you can do; that's absolutely bad. Check here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html. Put the await outside

Comment: The main problem using this approach is that after slipping the dismissable element, it flashes for a fragment of second.

`onDismissed: (direction) async {
 await MyContent().delete(snapshot.data[index]);
 setState(() {
        myContents = getMyContents(myContent.id);
 });
},`